# Path relative to another in bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a bat file, and one of the commands need a project path and a file path relative to the project.

For example

```
awesomecommand.exe project=C:\MyProject file="myfiles\file1.fbx"
```

I am iterating through all files in C:\MyProject (where my .bat file is located):

```
for /R "%~dp0" %%f in (*.fbx) do (
    ....
)
```

and I need to get the `%%f` path relative to `%dp0`. So if `%%f = C:\MyProject\myfiles\file1.fbx` and `%~dp0="C:\MyProject"`, I need the result to be `"myfiles\file1.fbx"`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for ... (
    set P=%%f
    set P=!P:%~dp0=!
    echo !P!
)
```

will remove the startup directory from P. (%~dp0 contains a trailing slash)

Answer (score 0):

`xcopy` command can be used to retrieve the list of files with relative paths

```
pushd "%~dp0"
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in ('xcopy "." "%temp%" /s /l ^| find "\"') do (
    echo %%b
)
popd
```

The list of files retrieved in in the format

```
.\folder\file.ext
.\file.ext
....
```

The `for` command `delims` and `tokens` handle the removal of the starting characters to leave the format requested